# Angular forEach all object from class

Tags: angular, foreach

is there any way in angular 2 (v. 2.4.0) to make for loop, or forEach loop taking every objects from class? I mean

```
export interface RegistrationDataInterface {
first_name: string;
    surname: string;
    used_name: string;
    email: string;
}
export class Smth{
registrationSharingData: RegistrationDataInterface;
 checkOut(){
forEach(item from this.registrationSharingData)
{
    if(item!="null")
    {//dosmth}
}}}
```

I dont want to make 20 ifs, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this,

```
for (let item of this.registrationSharingData){

}
```

since you want to check inside the Object, you don't need a loop,

```
checkOut(){
   You can just access the properties like this.registrationSharingData.whateverfield
}
```

Comment: Type 'RegistrationDataInterface' is not an array type or a string type.

Comment: is not it an array?

Comment: Nope, sorry I wasn't clear I need to pick all the items (first_name, surname, etc) from just 1 class, not from array of classes + I edited my example code

Comment: I know that I can access the properties like that :) I just wanted to check my every field using loop or smth, because I dont want to write ifs for every of them, it can be impossible as well.

Comment: you cannot loop over object

Comment: You can loop through object properties using the `for (var key in object)` loop. If this fits you I'll post an answer.